# Elasticsearch NEST: How to query with multiple fields expressions (multi_match or bool) with distributed boosts

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, nest

Did anyone face with a problem to combine boosted sub-queries using NEST?

Here example of query to Solr:

```
(field_exact:"value" AND didyoumean_field:value* AND field:value* AND value)^200 
OR 
(anotherfield_exact:"{0}"^100 AND didyoumean_anotherfield:value*^1 AND
 anotherfield:value*)^100
```

As you can see boosting applies to both - fields and whole expressions.

Please help me how i can to do similar query using NEST?

Comment: This looks like Lucene query syntax, in which case it can be used in a `query_string` query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: Yes it is. But How can it be done by NEST without Lucene syntax but by object model?

Comment: Have you tried Dismax query parser? It supports multiple subqueries.

Comment: I need the solution that shows how Lucene's syntax like above to do with NEST.